# MongoDB - Update objects in a document's List

Tags: java, mongodb, database

i  have the following List of documents , `List<Project> projectList`

```
"projectsList": [
    {
        "projectNumber": 1
        "projectName": "kjsd",
        "projectURL": "lkjsand",
        "projectDate": "Oct 7, 2016 12:00:00 AM",
        "projectOccupation": "kaijiuhdsa",
        "projectProposal": "aus asdig agduya"
    },
    {
        "projectNumber": 2
        "projectName": "alan walker",
        "projectURL": "lkjsand",
        "projectDate": "Oct 7, 2016 12:00:00 AM",
        "projectOccupation": "kaijiuhdsa",
        "projectProposal": "aus asdig agduya"
    },
    {
        "projectNumber": 3
        "projectName": "",
        "projectURL": "",
        "projectOccupation": "",
        "projectProposal": ""
    }

]
```

I have two project object which contain

```
Project oldProject= new Project("kjsd","lkjsand","Oct 7, 2016 12:00:00 AM","kaijiuhdsa","aus asdig agduya")
```

I need to update

```
Project newProject= new Project("kjsd","http","Oct 7, 2016 12:00:00 AM","kaijiuhdsa","ocr")
```

**How to update oldProject with newProject in mongoDB using java driver ?**

Comment: Your document in mongodb is a `projectList` object or a `Project` object?

Comment: my document it projectList

Comment: Can any key in inside the Project be considered as a unique key?

Comment: i have unique objectID key for each user ,i don't have in Project unique key

Comment: If I am updating `newProject` I need to find it this doc across multiple `projectList` arrays. Is there any unique combination which identifies a `Project` object?

Comment: i edit and put unique value for each project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer in MongoDB. I guess you can convert it into appropriate Java methods.

```
db.col.update(
    {"projectsList.projectNumber": 1}, 
    {$set: {
      "projectsList.$.projectUrl": "http",
      "projectsList.$.projectProposal": "ocr"
    }})
```